# Entity Framework object real update - no duplication

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, sql-update

I'm trying to update an object in my database using entity framework 4.1 with code-first and SQL Server 2008. My object's class has a ID field of int type. The problem is that when I update my object and invoke SaveChanges on my DbContext so the database creates a copy of the datarow rather then update the one I already have. I don't want this, I just would like a clean update like in the old-fashioned SQL command UPDATE. How can I fix this?

```
 Nation nation = (nationDB.Nations.Where(m => m.name == "France")).SingleOrDefault();

 if (nation != null)
 {
   Nation modNation = nationDB.Nations.Find(nation.ID);
   modNation.Level++;
 }

 nationDB.SaveChanges();

public class Nation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int name { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the id field the primary key? Please post some code.

Comment: Why do you update modNation instead of nation? Also show your Nation entity.

Comment: Updating directly nation could, of course, be done . I was just performing a dummy query to try out the system. But the problem stays even if I update directly nation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update it you must first read it from the database, change it, then save it.

If you create a new entity in code, even with an existing key, EF will treat it as a new entity.

Comment: I got the same result even if I do not create any enty in code.

Comment: I was somehow creating a new entity in code without realizing it. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `ObjectStateManager` has registered your object as being in the `Added` state. Try to set its status to `Modified` (by calling [`GetObjectStateEntry(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738902.aspx) and checking/modifying the `State` property).

Comment: How can I call GetObjectStateEntry?

Comment: @Francesco: Check the `DbContext` class, the `IObjectContextAdapter` interface, and the `ObjectStateManager` property in the `ObjectContext` class.

Comment: I tried to set the State to modified without success. nationDB.Entry(nation).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;